# Binding multiple properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties

I'm trying to draw a bezier curve and bind all its values:

```
<PathFigure StartPoint="20,20" IsClosed="False">
     <BezierSegment Point1="70,130" Point2="220,20" Point3="180,160"/>
</PathFigure>
```

So in all cases a 'Point' or StartPoint is defined I'd like to bind it to values in a class independently.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently than manually binding each property?

Answer (score -1):

For this specific question, you could do as following:

Basically we are still using MVVM pattern. First you need `PathPoint` class and `PathFigureViewModel` class which represent your data.

```
public class PathPoint
{
    public int X
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class PathFigureViewModel
{
    public PathPoint StartPoint
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public PathPoint Point1
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public PathPoint Point2
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public PathPoint Point3
    {
        get; set;
    }

}
```

Then you could define your `PathFigure` as following:

```
<PathFigure x:Name="PathFigure1" StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint, Converter={StaticResource PointConvertor}}" IsClosed="False">
     <BezierSegment Point1="{Binding Point1, Converter={StaticResource PointConvertor}}" Point2="{Binding Point2, Converter={StaticResource PointConvertor}}" Point3="{Binding Point3, Converter={StaticResource PointConvertor}}"/>
</PathFigure>
```

Notice that there is a converter above which converts `PathPoint` to `System.Windows.Point` as following:

```
public class PointToPathPointConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var p = value as PathPoint;
        return new System.Windows.Point(p.X, p.Y);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally you need to set the DataContext. Since the `PathFigure` doesn't expose `DataContext` property, you could set the `DataContext` property of its parent `Path` object. Something like following:

```
PathFigureViewModel vm = new PathFigureViewModel();
vm.StartPoint = new PathPoint() { X = 20, Y = 20 };
vm.Point1 = new PathPoint() { X = 70, Y = 130 };
vm.Point2 = new PathPoint() { X = 220, Y = 20 };
vm.Point3 = new PathPoint() { X = 180, Y = 160 };

this.Path.DataContext = vm;
```

Now it is done.